# Array push doesnt work the first time

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following code to run a function every second

```
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000);
var global = [];
function timer()
{
    var strJSON = '[{"id":"1","timeout":"2013-09-11 03:00:00"},{"id":"2","timeout":"2013-09-11 03:00:00"}]';
    var currentRequest = [];
    var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(strJSON);
    for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++) {
        var id = obj[i].id;
        var timeout = obj[i].timeout;
        if(id in global)
        {
            alert(id+' in array');
        } else {
            alert(id+' not in array');
            alert(id+' added');
            global.push(id);
        }
    }
}
```

Im using it to keep the global variable updated but without duplicates. However, when the script runs, the second id is said to be added in the first run but it is not really added as i get the following output:

/** FIRST RUN **/

- 1 not in array
- 1 added
- 2 not in array
- 2 added

/** SECOND RUN **/

- 1 in array
- 2 not in array
- 2 added

/** THIRD RUN **/

- 1 in array
- 2 in array

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5):

`id in global` is not used to check an element in an array. You need to use `.indexOf` instead.

```
> "1" in ["1","2"]
true
> "2" in ["1","2"]
false
```

`property in object` is to check whether an property exist in an object.

Array is 0-indexed, so `"0" in ["1","2"]` and `"1" in ["1", "2"]` would be true, but not `"2"`.

So you need to change

```
if(id in global)
```

to

```
if (global.indexOf(id) > -1)
```

*Note: You need a shim for old browsers which doesn't support `indexOf` method of array.*